# If well-founded induction holds, then the relation $\to$ on a reduction system terminates

Tags: reductions, term-rewriting

I am trying to understand a proof from "Term Rewriting and All That" by Baader and Nipkow.

Well-founded induction (WFI) is the following statement:

> $\forall x \in A(\forall y \in A(x \stackrel{+}{\to}y \Rightarrow P(y))\Rightarrow P(x)) \Longrightarrow \forall x\in A (P(x))$

Here is the proof I cannot understand.

> Theorem: If well-founded induction holds, then the relation $\to$ on a reduction system terminates.
>
> Proof: by WFI, where $P(x):=$ "there exist no infinite chain starting from $x$". The induction step is simple: If there exist no infinite chains starting from any successor of $x$, then there exist no infinite chains starting from $x$. Hence, the premise of WFI holds, and we can conclude that $P(x)$ holds for all $x$ i.e., $\to$ terminates.

Why can we define $P(x)$ to be "there exist no infinite chain starting from $x$"?

Answer (score 1):

Well-founded induction, like all other forms of induction, holds for *any* predicate $P$. That can mean two different things:

1. Well-founded induction holds for every predicate which you can express in your formal system.
2. Well-founded induction holds for every subset $P \subseteq A$.

Either way, informally speaking you can define $P$ to be whatever you want.

Formally speaking, you might run into set-theoretic issues, those that separate naive (or elementary) set theory from axiomatic set theory. But presumably this is not the focus of the book, so you can just ignore such issues.

(The gap is that in case 1, you need to show how to express $P$, and in case 2, you need to show that the set $\{x \in A : \text{there exists no infinite chain starting at $x$}\}$ exists.)

Comment: How could one even start to show that the set $\{x \in X : \text{there exists no infinite chain starting at x}\}$ exists? The way I see it, it does not even necessarily have to exist, give an arbitrary relation $\to$ on the set $A$.

Comment: Are you familiar with axiomatic set theory? If not, you should either ignore this issue, or read some lecture notes on axiomatic set theory.

Comment: I know elementary set theory. Not sure what constitutes axiomatic set theory. Which part of axiomatic set theory is relevant though? Thanks!

Comment: In other words, you are not familiar with axiomatic set theory. I cannot help you any further at this stage. Moreover, I don't really understand your problem. What would it mean, for you, that the set doesn't exist? It just consists of all $x \in A$ such that there is no infinite chain starting at $x$.